# Unity v3 - RegistrationByConvention - Could not load type exception

Tags: c#, unity-container, aop, enterprise-library-6

I am using Enterprise Library 6 and Unity v.3.5.0.0

**The following error occurs:**

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Manageability.ConfigurationSectionManageabilityProviderAttribute'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

**when using this code to register multiple types with the container automatically by using a set of rules and conventions (Registration by Convention)**

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
    .Where(x => (x.IsPublic == true) &&
    (x.GetInterfaces().Any() == true) &&
    (x.IsAbstract == false) &&
    (x.IsClass == true) &&
    x.Namespace == "Company.Project.Data.DA.NW" ),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, type => (container.Registrations.Select(x => x.RegisteredType)
    .Any(r => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(r) == true) == true) ? WithName.TypeName(type) : WithName.Default(type),
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

**UPDATE:**

The type:

> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Manageability.ConfigurationSectionManageabilityProviderAttribute

is not a part of EntLib 6 anymore, but in Entlib 5.

**Stacktrace:**

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Manageability.ConfigurationSectionManageabilityProviderAttribute'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +145
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +162
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg) +87
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +438 
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit) +64
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit) +87
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit) +13
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly
>   element) +57
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.AllClasses.IsSystemAssembly(Assembly a) +78 
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__f(Assembly
>   a) +72    System.Linq.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext() +48
>
>   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +168
>   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +152
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer
>   container, IEnumerable`1 types, Func`2 getFromTypes, Func`2 getName,
>   Func`2 getLifetimeManager, Func`2 getInjectionMembers, Boolean
>   overwriteExistingMappings) +1323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a solution but a workaround:

I simply replace the first parameter:

```
AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
    .Where(x => (x.IsPublic == true) &&
    (x.GetInterfaces().Any() == true) &&
    (x.IsAbstract == false) &&
    (x.IsClass == true) &&
    x.Namespace == "Company.Project.Data.DA.NW" )
```

and replaced it with a custom function (assFilter is a List of string with simple Assembly names and classFilter a list of namespaces)

```
var filteredAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => assFilter.Contains(a.FullName.Split(',')[0]));

    List<Type> allClasses = new List<Type>();
    foreach (var assembly in filteredAssemblies)
    {
        var classArray = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic &&
            !t.IsAbstract &&
            t.IsClass == true &&
            classFilter.Contains(t.Namespace));
        if (classArray != null && classArray.Count() > 0)
            allClasses.AddRange(classArray);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find an actual solution to this?

Comment: Didn't use it long time, can't remember. I switched to maintained DI fx

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks!  For the record, I had trouble when I tried to upgrade from EL 3.1 to 6 since that's all thats on nuget and we're switching to nuget packages.  My solution was to publish EL 3.1 packages to a private feed and just reference those instead of upgrading.